# Comparators Dragging Each Other Down

Tags: voltage, timing, comparator

I've assembled a circuit which uses RC timing compared to the voltage across a potentiometer. It is intended to run the motor in this fashion:

```
ON -----------------------       -----------------------
                          |     |
OFF                        -----
```

by triggering the comparators like this:

```
    ON ------------------
CMP1                     |
    OFF                   -----------------------------

    ON                           ----------------------
CMP2                            |
    OFF-------------------------
```

However, the circuit operates exactly opposite this behavior. It is on when I intend for it to be off, and off when it needs to be on. I think that one comparator may be dragging the output of the other to ground, but adding diodes doesn't seem to fix this.

[image]

The comparators in this diagram are on the LM393 chip. I'm very limited in the variety of components that I can choose from, and something that relies mostly on diodes and/or resistors works perfectly.

Comment: What model comparator are you using? Where did you try adding diodes?

Comment: Comparators that are designed to be connected like you drew usually have *open collector* outputs. That means they can pull down, but not pull up (That's probably why you need the pull-up R16). That means you can produce a *wired AND* connection by tying two outputs together. You can't create a *wired OR* with typical comparators. You will need some kind of added gate or a couple of transistors to create the OR function you want.

Comment: @thePhoton I'm using LM393, and I added diodes between the comparator outputs and base of the transistors. I thought adding the diodes would emulate a logic OR.

Comment: There is something wrong: According to this schematic the base of the transistor and the comparator outputs are connected directly to GND.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LM393 has open collector outputs. That means they can pull down, but not pull up (That's probably why you need the pull-up R16).

The open collector output means you can produce a wired AND connection by tying two outputs together. You can't create a wired OR with typical comparators. You will need some kind of added gate or a couple of transistors to create the OR function you want.

If you want to create the OR function using diodes, you will need a separate pull-up for each of the two comparator's outputs.

[image: Wired OR circuit for open-collector comparators]

Answer (score 0):

The way you have your open-collector outputs configured gives you a `NOR` function, and you want it to be an `OR`. You can make this work by introducing an inversion in the output transistor and swapping the inputs of the comparators.

As you have the output configured now, you have a NPN transistor configured as an emitter-follower, which probably won't drive your motor as well as you might like. I would recommend switching the NPN transistor for a PNP transistor, which will use a more favorable topology for switching the motor, make it easier to drive with your open-collector outputs, and provide the logic inversion for proper operation.

Comment: I wish I could use a PNP, but my supplies are limited. Otherwise, I wouldn't be asking this question. The way I'm forced to do it is not the way I'd prefer.

Answer (score 0):

Change from:
[image]

to:

[image]

Open collector pull-up is optional.
When Open collector comparators are active low the PNP transitor is active with 35 mA base current.  The collector will saturate high with a load of 350 to 700 mA. @ ~ 7.3 V 
If there are any changes needed to match motor requirements. Feel free to adjust.
When both comparator turns off, the motor will coast to t stop. If you want active stop and push pull compl. emitter follower would work and then swap +_ inputs on comparator..